# Flush not invoking file change

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing a program where one process A reads the data appended to file by another process B.I am using ReadDirectoryChangesW for the notification.The problem is that the notification is not being generated until I close the handle in B although I am flushing contents to file using fflush.The code is a given below

File Writer:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp=_fsopen("log.txt", "a", _SH_DENYNO);

    char str[4096];

    for(int i=1;i<4096;i++)
        str[i]=i;

    while(true){
        fwrite(str,1,4096,fp);
        fflush(fp);
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

File Reader:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <assert.h> 
#include <share.h>

void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=_fsopen("C:\\Users\\dell\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\FileWriter\\FileWriter\\log.txt", "r", _SH_DENYNO);
    int last_size=0,new_size=0;

    if(fp==NULL)
        return ;

    HANDLE m_hMonitoredDir = CreateFile(TEXT("C:\\Users\\dell\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\FileWriter\\FileWriter"), FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, 
        FILE_SHARE_DELETE|FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL );

    if ( m_hMonitoredDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        printf("error");
        return;
    }

    char szBuf[ MAX_PATH ];
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    int flag=0;
    char *buffer;

    while ( ReadDirectoryChangesW( m_hMonitoredDir, szBuf, MAX_PATH, FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,&dwBytesRead, NULL, NULL ))
    {
        PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION pstFileNotif = (PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION)( szBuf );
        if ( pstFileNotif->Action == FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED ) 
        {
            char szNotifFilename[ MAX_PATH ] = { 0 };
            if ( int iNotifFilenameLen = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_OEMCP, NULL, 
                pstFileNotif->FileName, 
                pstFileNotif->FileNameLength / sizeof( WCHAR ), 
                szNotifFilename, sizeof( szNotifFilename ) / sizeof( char ), 
                NULL, NULL ) )
            {

                if ( strcmp("log.txt", szNotifFilename ) == 0 )
                {   
                    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
                    new_size = ftell(fp);   
                    fseek(fp,last_size,SEEK_SET);
                    int size=new_size-last_size;
                    buffer=new char[size+1];
                    fread(buffer,1,size,fp);
                    buffer[size]='\0';
                    printf("%s",buffer);
                    free(buffer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me get notifications as soon as I use fflush in B ?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/26/10251026.aspx

Comment: Is it possible the OS also has its own caching?

Comment: a pipe may be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, CreateNamedPipe maybe the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a commit-to-disk by calling `_flushall` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9xk9ehd.aspx )

or see this article ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148505 ) on how to force a commit-to-disk. You need to link with `commode.obj` to force `fflush` to commit-to-disk automatically.

The alternative might be to `fclose` the file each time, and reopen the file in append mode, if you are only doing it every 2 seconds (the overhead is small).

Comment: can you tell how to link commode.obj file in visual studio

Comment: add `commode.obj` to Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.  According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` (emphasis mine):

> Any change to the last write-time of files in the watched directory or subtree causes a change notification wait operation to return. **The operating system detects a change to the last write-time only when the file is written to the disk.** For operating systems that use extensive caching, detection occurs only when the cache is sufficiently flushed.

[`fflush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) ensures that the file data is passed back to the operating system, but it does not guarantee that the data gets written to the disk, since typically a lot of caching is involved:

> Buffers are normally maintained by the operating system, which determines the optimal time to write the data automatically to disk: when a buffer is full, when a stream is closed, or when a program terminates normally without closing the stream. The commit-to-disk feature of the run-time library lets you ensure that critical data is written directly to disk rather than to the operating-system buffers.

As others have said in the comments, you may be better of using named pipes for your goals, since you're only dealing with a single known file.

Comment: When I write the file in notepad and press ctrl+s it is flushed to disk and event is triggered. Any ideas on how notepad flushes data on ctrl+s

Comment: @saadhussain: Notepad doesn't keep its file handle open during normal execution.  When you ask it to save, it opens a new file handle, writes the data, and closes the file handle.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66052/

For us, linking with commode.obj didn't work.

However, this approach did:

When we opened our file using fopen, we included the "c" mode option as the LAST OPTION:

```
fopen( path, "wc") // w - write mode, c - allow immediate commit to disk
```

Then when you want to force a flush to disk, call

```
_flushall()
```

We made this call before calling

```
fclose()
```

We experienced the exact issue you described and this approach fixed it.

From that above site:

*"Microsoft C/C++ version 7.0 introduces the "c" mode option for the fopen()
function. When an application opens a file and specifies the "c" mode, the
run-time library writes the contents of the file buffer to disk when the
application calls the fflush() or _flushall() function. "*